# Tricky Questions Answers associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

So I have 3 models..

A User model, a Questions model and an Answer model.

A user has_many questions, and questions belong_to user

A question has_one answer, and the answers belong_to the question.

Now I've created default seed questions that apply to all users i.e. @questions = Question.all

And these same questions every user can see, now how can I allow each user to write their own answer to these questions when they aren't directly associated with the question?

I.e. u.questions.answer returns answer is undefined.

Comment: `u.questions` will return an array, so calling `.answer` on it won't get you anything. Try `u.questions.first.answer` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks @MikeManfrin - still the same results tho, returns undefined method answer. One thought just came to mind, maybe I can add those questions to the user when a new user is created somehow? hm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a has many through association, with a link to the answer in the intermediate table. Thus:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :user_questions
end

class UserQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

In this way, you can create questions that you can associate with a user or not, and also link to their answer, where it exists.