# Is this the proper way to setup a has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have 4 models..

A User model, a Question model an Answer model and a User_Question model.

Now I've created default seed questions that apply to all users i.e. @questions = Question.all

And these same questions every user can see, now how can I allow each user to write their own answer to these questions when they aren't directly associated with the question? I was given a solution to create a has_many through association, I just want to make sure I've set it up correctly please see code below, thanks:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :user_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :user_questions

end
```

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer
  has_many :user_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :user_questions
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :answer
end
```

**user_question.rb**

```
class UserQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer

end
```

Comment: Why do you have user_question?

Comment: Thanks @ShaunFrostDukeJackson, I used that because my questions exist independently of users, so I created a user has_many questions through user_questions association it's an intermediate table with foreign keys to a user and to a question. So a UserQuestion can belong to an answer. Not sure if it's setup right though. Can you pls verify, it's my first time using a has_many through association.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you say your questions exist independently of users. Yet questions belongs to users.

My understand of this should be as follows:

User.rb

```
has_many :questions
has_many :answers
```

question.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :answers
```

answer.rb

```
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

Notice the plurals as well for belongs_to and has_many.

The link for the guide is here but I don't think you need user_questions.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: That's what I had initially but it didn't work which is why I added the user_questions has through many association. Pls see original post that led me to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338551/tricky-questions-answers-associations/20339536?noredirect=1#20339536 .I basically just need to know the proper way to setup as has_many through association.

Comment: It's MY question lol, I just need someone to help verify that I've setup the has_many through association properly. And copied a piece of my original question for context ;)

Comment: This way of modelling the associations would make the most sense given the problem described - has_many through is unnecessary.

Comment: Although, it may make sense to do something like User has_many answered_questions through answers, given the associations here.